# Get character array address then convert to pointer char

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I convert my string and bytearray to char array.

```
char nameData[90];
char passData[90];
strcpy(nameData, name.toStdString().c_str()); //string
strcpy(passData, pass.data()); //bytearray
```

Now I need to get the address of the nameData and passData to set it as a pointer?
Or is there an easy to convert the string and bytearray to char pointer?

I need to convert it to char pointer to store it to a file.

Comment: `name.toStdString().c_str()` could be all you need to do, or perhaps `name.toStdString().data()`. Hard to be sure. Can you add more of whatever suffering you intend for this `char` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to get the address of the nameData

A char pointer points to a char. It doesn't point to an array strictly speaking.

Your array is an array of char objects however. So, I take it that you actually mean *"I need to get the address of the first character of nameData"*.

It's quite simple. An array is implicitly convertible to a pointer to the first element of the array. In fact, the array name *decays* to this pointer whenever the value is used. So, simply assign the pointer:

`char* pointer = nameData;`

> I need to convert it to char pointer to store it to a file.

You probably don't even need the pointer variable. Simply pass the array directly to the function that takes the character pointer argument.

Comment: but how can I use the pointer? because *pointer only get the char[0] data, i can't used just a pointer. I need *pointer. is it possible?

Comment: @GraceJacinto `but how can I use the pointer?` It's a pointer. You can read its value, indirect through it, increment it etc. `I need *pointer. is it possible?` I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think just use the type conversion would be ok.
e.g. `char* pNameData = (char*) nameData`. In fact you can use the nameData directly as `char*` pointer in C or C++.